# Android Mapbox SDK v10: attribution position; UiSettings

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

How is possible to adjust the logo and attribution in `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView`?
In the older SDK v9, it was possible to simply set UiSettings via XML attributes (or by changing UiSettings programmatically).

```
mapbox:mapbox_uiAttributionMarginBottom="8dp"
mapbox:mapbox_uiAttributionMarginLeft="32dp"
```

Any idea how to achieve the same effect on Mapbox SDK v10?

Answer (score 4):

I am using Mapbox android 10.4.0 and this is how I do. Hope it helps!

```
 mapView.attribution.updateSettings {
            marginRight= 56F
            marginLeft= 56F
        }
 mapView.logo.updateSettings {
        marginBottom= 420F
        marginLeft= 320F
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this adjustment directly in the xml?

Answer (score 2):

Hello in v10+ they change to plugins, so the logo settings and UI settings you need to install:

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-logo:10.2.0'
```

in your Gradle.build file.

Source: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-android/tree/main/plugin-logo