# How to move MapBox logo and attribution in a snapshot in Android?

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm using MapBox `com.mapbox.maps.Snapshotter` to make a map snapshot:

```
            var snapshotter = Snapshotter(
                context, MapSnapshotOptions.Builder()
                    .size(Size(950f, 450f))
                    .resourceOptions(
                        ResourceOptions.Builder()
                            .accessToken(context.getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
                            .build()
                    )
                    .build()
            )
            snapshotter.setStyleUri(Style.OUTDOORS)
...
            snapshotter.start {
                it?.bitmap().let { bitmap ->
...
            }
```

It generates a bitmap with the Mapbox logo and map attribution positioned at the bottom of the image. Is it possible to relocate both the attribution and the logo to the right side and rotate them by 90°, aligning them with the right border of the bitmap?

The solutions I have come across, such as the one provided in this Stack Overflow post ([Android Mapbox SDK v10: attribution position; UiSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69284155/android-mapbox-sdk-v10-attribution-position-uisettings)), pertain to displaying the map on a device rather than generating a snapshot.